# Who played Darth Vader during the Dagobah Dark Side Cave scene

Tags: star-wars, darth-vader

I've read where Bob Anderson played Darth Vader during all the light saber/fight scenes for The Empire Strikes Back and Return Of The Jedi. Does that include this scene?

Comment: It was Mark Hamill. Didn't you see the face when the mask came off?

Comment: @Xantec I am surprised how they sacrifice their lives to make money.

Comment: Why would it not include that scene?

Comment: This seems like a trivia question to me... And it seems to fit one of the criteria the FAQ lists as questions we should not ask here: "there is no actual problem to be solved".  I can understand wanting to know this, but does it change the storyline, or appreciation for the movie, or clarify a nuance in the plot that is not understood? It seems to met the criteria of "too localized".

Answer (score 6):

From Anderson's obituary:

> "David Prowse wasn't very good with a sword and Bob couldn't get him to do the moves," said Anderson's former assistant, Leon Hill. "Fortunately Bob could just don the costume and do it himself."

This means that most likely, ALL the fight scenes in ESB were Anderson's, Dahobah included.

Being that Lucas never wanted to even acknowlegde Anderson's work, don't expect any official confirmation on individual scenes from GL.

Comment: Bob Anderson appears to be listed as a stunt double in ESB and RoTJ, but uncredited Fight Arranger in ANH: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bob_Anderson_%28fencer%29#Stunts